# Does Active Directory support certificateExactMatch LDAP matching rule?

Tags: active-directory, certificate

[RFC 4523](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4523.txt) describes a matching rule for X.509 certificates called certificateExactMatch (2.5.13.34). Using this rule, one should be able to execute an LDAP query to get a user object by providing only the certificate's serial number (i.e. 123) and issuer (i.e. DC=My,DC=Domain):

```
(userCertificate:certificateExactMatch:={ serialNumber 123, issuer "DC=My,DC=Domain" } )
```

or (older syntax):

```
(userCertificate:certificateExactMatch:=123$DC=My,DC=Domain)
```

Does Active Directory support **certificateExactMatch**? If not by default, is there a way to add this matching rule?

I know that I can search for a certificate by binary equality (e.g. (userCertificate;binary=\12\34\AB\CD...) ) but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will find in [Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the Microsoft documentation. I don't think that **certificateExactMatch** is supported there.

You can check more accuratly with [Valid Syntaxes for Attributes in the Active Directory Schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773309%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)